# flutter in app purchase , cancel and refund notification after 5 minutes using test card

Tags: flutter, dart, in-app-purchase

I am new to Flutter and trying to apply in-app purchase in my Flutter application , but receive a cancellation notification from Google after 5 minutes, i am using the official in-app purchase plugin from Flutter and here is my snapshot:

```
class PurchaseFullVersion {
final InAppPurchase \_inAppPurchase = InAppPurchase.instance;
String \_notice = '';
HomeProvider? homeProvider;
final List\<PurchaseDetails\> \_purchases = \<PurchaseDetails\>\[\];

void setHomeProvider(HomeProvider homeProvider) {
this.homeProvider = homeProvider;
\_initPurchaseListener();
}

Future\<bool\> purchaseFullVersion(List\<String\> productIds) async {
try {
// Check if the user has already purchased any of the products
if (await hasPurchased(productIds)) {
\_updateNotice('You have already purchased the app.');
return true;
}

      if (!await _inAppPurchase.isAvailable()) {
        _updateNotice('Purchase is not available for this version now!');
        return false;
      }
    
      // Use the product IDs passed as a parameter
      final ProductDetailsResponse productDetailsResponse =
          await _inAppPurchase.queryProductDetails(productIds.toSet());
    
      if (productDetailsResponse.error != null) {
        _updateNotice(
            'Purchase is not available ${productDetailsResponse.error}');
        return false;
      }
    
      final List<ProductDetails> products =
          productDetailsResponse.productDetails;
    
      if (products.isEmpty) {
        _updateNotice('Products are not available');
        return false;
      }
    
      final ProductDetails productDetails = products.first;
      final PurchaseParam purchaseParam =
          PurchaseParam(productDetails: productDetails);
    
      final bool purchaseResult =
          await _inAppPurchase.buyNonConsumable(purchaseParam: purchaseParam);
    
      if (purchaseResult) {
        _handleSuccessfulPurchase([productDetails.id]);
        return true;
      } else {
        _updateNotice('Purchase failed or was canceled.');
        return false;
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      _handlePurchaseError(e);
      return false;
    }

}

Future\<bool\> hasPurchased(List\<String\> productIds) async {
String deviceId = await SharedPreferencesUtils.getStoredDeviceId();
List\<String\> purchasedProductIdsList =
await FirestoreService.getPurchaseInfo(deviceId);

    // Check if there is any intersection between the two lists
    return productIds
        .any((productId) => purchasedProductIdsList.contains(productId));

}

void \_initPurchaseListener() {
\_inAppPurchase.purchaseStream
.listen((List\<PurchaseDetails?\> purchaseDetailsList) {
// Filter out null values
List\<PurchaseDetails\> filteredList =
purchaseDetailsList.whereType\<PurchaseDetails\>().toList();
\_handlePurchaseDetailsList(filteredList);
});
}

List\<PurchaseDetails\> \_handlePurchaseDetailsList(
List\<PurchaseDetails\> purchaseDetailsList) {
\_purchases.addAll(purchaseDetailsList); // Add purchases to the list
for (PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails in purchaseDetailsList) {
if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased) {
\_handleSuccessfulPurchase(\[purchaseDetails.productID\]);

        // Check if the purchase is non-consumable
        if (purchaseDetails.productID == homeProvider?.getSelectedProductId()) {
          _acknowledgePurchase(purchaseDetails);
        }
      }
    }
    return _purchases; // Return the updated purchases list

}

void \_acknowledgePurchase(PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails) async {
try {
// Acknowledge the purchase
await \_inAppPurchase.completePurchase(purchaseDetails);

      // Your additional logic after acknowledging the purchase
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      _handlePurchaseError(e);
    }

}

void \_handleSuccessfulPurchase(List\<String\> productIds) async {
\_updateNotice('Purchase successful!');
homeProvider?.updatePurchaseStatus(true);
String deviceId = await SharedPreferencesUtils.getStoredDeviceId();

    // Store purchase information in Firestore
    await FirestoreService.storePurchaseInfo(
        deviceId, [productIds.isNotEmpty ? productIds.first : '']);
    
    // Find the successful purchase in the list and acknowledge it
    for (PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails in _purchases) {
      if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased &&
          purchaseDetails.productID == productIds.first) {
        _acknowledgePurchase(purchaseDetails);
        break; // Break after acknowledging the purchase
      }
    }
    
    // Remove the acknowledged purchase from the list
    _purchases.removeWhere((purchaseDetails) =>
        purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased &&
        purchaseDetails.productID == productIds.first);

}

void \_handlePurchaseError(PlatformException e) {
print('Platform exception: $e');
\_updateNotice('An error occurred during the purchase.');
}

void \_updateNotice(String message) {
\_notice = message;
print(message);
}

String get notice =\> \_notice;
}
```

i tried to use different android emulators and the same issue , also tested that on physical android phone but also the same issue , receive cancel and refund notification after 5 minutes

Comment: In Test mode, subscription durations are 1,5,10 minutes. 
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/test

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but does this affect the real app when go to the production phase?

Comment: No, it doesn't affect